# Handling WinApi edit control with subclass of GLFW

Tags: winapi, glfw

I'm a newbie in winapi handling and opengl rendering. I try to use GLFW window to render my graphics and handling messages from WinApi windows. For handle messages from winapi i am create a subclass of GLFW window and replace wndproc function like this:

```
window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Window", nullptr, nullptr);
GLWINDOW = window;
HWND hWnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);
SetParent(hWnd, mainWindow);
LONG nNewStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_POPUP | WS_CHILDWINDOW;
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, nNewStyle);
ULONG_PTR cNewStyle = GetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_STYLE) | CS_DBLCLKS;
SetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCL_STYLE, cNewStyle);
SetWindowSubclass(hWnd, &msgProc, 0, 0);
glfwShowWindow(window);
```

Then i create my buttons and wndproc function. That work well, i can process messages from this buttons and click on it. But when i create "edit control", it doesn't react on my mouse clicks and key inputs. What do I need to do to make it work?
My wndproc:

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK msgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
 lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
 {
 PAINTSTRUCT PS;
 switch(message)
 {
    case WM_CREATE:
    break;
 case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
 case WM_PAINT:
    BeginPaint(hWnd, &PS);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &PS);
    break;
 case WM_COMMAND:
    if(LOWORD(wParam)==1)
        glEnabled = true;
    if(LOWORD(wParam)==2)
    {
        printf("system: application terminated \n");
        terminate = true;
    }
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are both windows referenced in the `SetParent` call owned by the same thread?

Comment: Show us your Window Proc you used to subclass. The code you showed isn't relevant.

Comment: @xMRi Added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your WM_PAINT routine. You don't let the WM_PAINT to be handled by the edit control.

You gave the edit control no chance to display anything. Subclassing means: Just do that what is neccesary. Let the rest be handled by the control. Also calling `DefWindowProc` is wrong for subclassing. You have to use

```
 return CallWindowProc(wndprocOrig, hwnd, wm, wParam, lParam);
```

If this windowproc is used for the edit control it wonders me, that you handle WM_COMMAND message in it. WM_COMMAND messages are not sent to the control. They are sent to the parent window. Also there is a break missing.

Please read the [MSDN for further details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Advice for the future: As you are new to SO, please offer as much information and code as possible when you ask a question.